# AFImageRequestOperation with SDWebImage issue

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, sdwebimage

I use AFImageRequestOperation to download some icons, meanwhile use SDWebImage to download some pics for main view. Each AFImageRequestOperation is added to my publicOperationQueue defined in app delegate, its maxConcurrentOperationCount is set to 10. Strange thing is that sometimes one or two of my 10+ icons will be replaced by some pic in main view, which should be downloaded by SDWebImage. And when I set a larger maxConcurrentOperationCount which is bigger than my icon counts, it works fine. I doubt if it has something to do with multiple NSOperationQueues sharing some resources and maxConcurrentOperationCount. Any one could help?

```
//below is the icon downloading code
//============================//
for(NSString *url in picUrls)
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [urlRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
        [urlRequest addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
        [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
            NSString *imageName = trimNilOrNuLL([url lastPathComponent]);
            if(imageName.length > 0)
            {
                NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(responseObject);
                [imageData writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] atomically:YES];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];

        [[AppShare appDelegate].publicOperationQueue addOperation:requestOperation];
    }
//============================//
```

and for SDWebImage, I use - (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url method in UIImageView+WebCache category to download pic

Comment: add some relevant code please

Answer (score 0):

OK,From the question found that you are using AFNetworking .Then for image downloading why dont you use the [UIImageView Extention](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m) of AFNetworking?
You dont have to implement any queue or anything for this
some code like this is enough i think

```
  [self.imageview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: UIImageView category in AFNetworking doesn't provide disk cache, while SDWebImage does.